# How to debug the content of a closure

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Suppose I have the following code inside a webpage:

```js
(function() {
  var foo = 0;
  function bar() {
    foo += 1;
  }
  bar();
})();
```

How can I inspect the value of the variable `foo` and/or call the function `bar` from the console sometime after the page has loaded.

I am using Google Chrome and I cannot edit the source code.

Comment: why not return the function `bar` and put a log of `foo` in its function body ?

Comment: @zb22 assume that I am debugging a page which I do not control so I cannot edit the code. If I could use Chrome's developer tools to overwrite the code that would be acceptable.

Comment: If you can see it, you can edit it (and/or put a break point in it).
Am I wrong?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to be able to inspect the variables on-demand so installing breakpoints on all possible places that modify variable(s) was not practical.

My solution was to place a function inside the closure which could be accessed globally. It could be done like so:

1. Set a breakpoint inside the closure. Reload the page if necessary.
2. When the debugger is paused inside the closure, enter the following code in the console:

```js
window.baz = function() {
    // debugger;
    bar();
    console.log(foo);
}
```

You can now call the function inside the console anytime and it should be able to access the variables defined in the closure.

---

[image: breakpoint setup and code injection]

[image: execute the injected code]

Answer (score 0):

chrome has a dev tool you can use , just put a break inside the inner closure and then test your variables in the console .
the console is relative to the state of your code , if you stop at a certain point , some variables/functions will be defined/undefined to that point .

by your example:

```
(function() {
  var foo = 0;
  function bar() {
    foo += 1;
    //make the break here
  }
})();
```

you can't edit the source js code of the page , that will make every web page open to hacks...

Comment: But I don't know if/when `bar` will be called!